# ADT Plugin for Eclipse on Ubuntu 10.10 not accepting license

Tags: eclipse, licensing, eclipse-adt

When I try to install the ADT plugin for Eclipse on Ubuntu 10.10 the installation does not get past the licence screen. No matter how many times I check the radio button to accept the license, the NEXT and FINISH buttons do not highlight. I might be missing something obvious, but I have tried all kinds of things and nothing works. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Aha! You can ignore the above fellows, it worked after I went back and did a new fetch of the ADT plugin by removing the https from the url from google and using only http. So nothing more to do here it all works fine!